# How to Make a Code Run Multiple Times with Random Numbers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, random

I have a code that involves generating a random number and then the rest of the calculations are based on that number. I want to run this 100x with 100 different random numbers, but obviously I don't want to manually run it and write down the final answer 100 times. Would I use a loop to get it to do this on its own? I am only familiar with writing loops where separate numbers are set for each run, like running a calculation with numbers 1-100 or with pulling out numbers from a vector. I am not sure how I would write one that runs a set number of times and generates a random number each time.

Comment: If you already have a `for` loop, then you can call a function like `rand`, `randn` or `randi` inside the loop to generate a different random number on each loop iteration. Alternatively, you could create 100 random numbers in one vector, for example: `x = rand(1,100);`. Then you can index that vector inside your `for` loop. For example, if your loop is `for i = 1:100`, then you can use `x(i)`.

Comment: I'm using the normrnd function. I already have that, I'm just not sure how to write a loop to get it to repeat and then store it in a vector. I tried doing "for i=1:100 x(i)=normrnd(mu,sigma)" but it didn't seem to work with the rest of my code.

Comment: It sounds like you are close. Can you paste your code into your question (by editing your question)? Then I can tell you exactly what you need to change.

Comment: nevermind! just had a stupid syntax error. that did work, thanks!